# What is the best way to store and download up to 5000 mp3 files for a react native app?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a type of flashcard application using react-native. The flashcard decks can contain up to 5000 mp3 files. I want the user to be able to download an entire deck when they first use it.

Currently, I am downloading each file individually using Google cloud public storage but this is brutally slow and some downloads timeout. Is there a place where I can download an entire folder of mp3 files instead of downloading each of them individually? I have seen that you can do it using AWS S3 but I have no idea how to do this from the client in react native. Thanks.

Comment: These 5000 mp3 files have to be stored on the user device or in the cloud ?

Comment: The files are stored on the cloud and I would like the user to be able to download the files and store them on the device when they want to.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wish to download the files, rather than having users access the files from the cloud when required?

Comment: I wanted the app to be able to work offline. However, I think I will now just stream the audio as they get to it. Thanks.